# How to evaluate this definite integral $\int_0^2(1-x^2)^\frac{1}{3}~dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

A student asked me to help him calculate this definite integral
$$\int_0^2(1-x^2)^\frac{1}{3}~dx$$
Although I have tried almost all the methods I have learned, I can not still do with it. I have tried the change of variable $x=\sec t$ , and the method of integral by parts. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Apparently it's kind of nasty: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+%281-x%5E2%29%5E%281%2F3%29+dx Hypergeometric functions, whatever those are, and you know you have a problem when your series expansion is full of gamma functions.

Comment: Where did the student get the question? Because this looks beyond first-year calculus to me. (unless they're missing an x multiplied by the integrand? ie. *$x(1-x^2)^{1/3}$* because then a simple substitution would have worked)

Comment: @Alec, that should be http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+0+to+2+of+%281-x%5E2%29%5E%281%2F3%29+dx&a=%5E_Real

Comment: My bad, yes. Thanks dfeuer.

Comment: @Alec, huh, I made the same mistake with the indefinite one. Oops.

Comment: @dfeuer I know, I copy pasted yours and added the bounds. :)

Comment: Are you sure that you did not forget something in the integrand definition ?

Comment: @dfeuer. I wonder how WA arrived to this result while Mathematica leads to a complex solution (1.35442 + 0.888726 I) !

Comment: you can find a solution, but in terms of special functions. Are you interested in that?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, it depends on which cube root is used.

Comment: What a good high school! :)

Comment: You can use the hypergeometric function: $$\int \sqrt[3]{1-x^2} \; dx = \frac{3x}{5}\sqrt[3]{1-x^2} +\frac{2x}{5}{\;}_2F_1 \left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3},\frac{3}{2},x^2 \right)$$

Comment: @Integrals and Series: It sounds great, but when we substitute $x=2$ into it we will get trouble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\int_0^2(1-x^2)^\frac{1}{3}~dx$

$=\int_1^{-\sqrt[3]3}x~d\left((1-x^3)^\frac{1}{2}\right)$

$=\int_1^{-\sqrt[3]3}\dfrac{3x^3(1-x^3)^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{2}dx$

$=\int_{-1}^\sqrt[3]3\dfrac{3(-x)^3(1-(-x)^3)^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{2}d(-x)$

$=\int_{-1}^\sqrt[3]3\dfrac{3x^3(1+x^3)^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{2}dx$

$=\int_{-1}^1\dfrac{3x^3(1+x^3)^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{2}dx+\int_1^\sqrt[3]3\dfrac{3x^3(1+x^3)^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{2}dx$

$=\int_{-1}^1\dfrac{3x^3(1+x^3)^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{2}dx+\int_1^\sqrt[3]3\dfrac{3x^\frac{3}{2}~(1+x^{-3})^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{2}dx$

For the binomial series of $(1+x)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ , $(1+x)^{-\frac{1}{2}}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!x^n}{4^n(n!)^2}$

$\therefore\int_{-1}^1\dfrac{3x^3(1+x^3)^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{2}dx+\int_1^\sqrt[3]3\dfrac{3x^\frac{3}{2}~(1+x^{-3})^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{2}dx$

$=\int_{-1}^1\dfrac{3x^3}{2}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!x^{3n}}{4^n(n!)^2}dx+\int_1^\sqrt[3]3\dfrac{3x^\frac{3}{2}}{2}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!x^{-3n}}{4^n(n!)^2}dx$

$=\int_{-1}^1\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{3(-1)^n(2n)!x^{3n+3}}{2^{2n+1}(n!)^2}dx+\int_1^\sqrt[3]3\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{3(-1)^n(2n)!x^{\frac{3}{2}-3n}}{2^{2n+1}(n!)^2}dx$

$=\biggl[\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{3(-1)^n(2n)!x^{3n+4}}{2^{2n+1}(n!)^2(3n+4)}\biggr]_{-1}^1+\biggl[\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{3(-1)^n(2n)!x^{\frac{5}{2}-3n}}{4^n(n!)^2(5-6n)}\biggr]_1^\sqrt[3]3$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{3(-1)^n(2n)!}{2^{2n+1}(n!)^2(3n+4)}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{3(-1)^n(2n)!(-1)^{3n+4}}{2^{2n+1}(n!)^2(3n+4)}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{3(-1)^n(2n)!3^{\frac{5}{6}-n}}{4^n(n!)^2(6n-5)}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{3(-1)^n(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2(6n-5)}$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{3(-1)^n(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2(6n-5)}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{3^\frac{11}{6}(-1)^n(2n)!}{12^n(n!)^2(6n-5)}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{3(4n+2)!}{4^{2n+1}((2n+1)!)^2(6n+7)}$

Answer (score 4):

No, no one can help your student calculate this definite integral. It is [too horribly nasty by far](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+0+to+2+of+%281-x%5E2%29%5E%281%2F3%29+dx&a=%5E_Real). Tell him to wait till he gets to grad school and see if he's still interested in awful integrals then.

Comment: Lol. Good answer. I'm assuming something must have been copied down incorrectly because there's no way that's a first-year integral question.

Comment: Actually the student that asked me the above problem is one of my undergraduate student, who takes part in my Calculus course.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x = 1 -u^3$, we can rewrite the integral $\mathcal{I}$ as

$$\mathcal{I} = \int_0^2\sqrt[3]{1-x^2}dx 
= 3\sqrt[3]{2}\int_{-1}^1 u^3 \left(1 - \frac{u^3}{2}\right)^{\frac13} du\\
$$
Since the power series expansion of $\left(1 - \frac{u^3}{2}\right)^{\frac13}$ at $u = 0$ has radius of convergence $> 1$, we can expand it inside the integral sign and evaluate 
the expansion term by term.  We have

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I} \stackrel{[\color{blue}{1}]}{=}& 3\sqrt[3]{2}\int_{-1}^1 u^3 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(-\frac13\right)_k}{k!}\left(\frac{u^3}{2}\right)^k du\\
=&3\sqrt[3]{2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-\frac13)_k}{k!}\frac{1}{3k+4}\left[\left(\frac12\right)^k - \left(-\frac12\right)^k\right]\\
\stackrel{[\color{blue}{2}]}{=}&\frac{3\sqrt[3]{2}}{4}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-\frac13)_k (\frac43)_k}{k!(\frac73)_k}
\left[\left(\frac12\right)^k - \left(-\frac12\right)^k\right]\\
=&\frac{3\sqrt[3]{2}}{4}\left[\,_2F_1(-\frac13,\frac43;\,\frac73;\,\frac12) -\,_2F_1(-\frac13,\frac43;\,\frac73;\,-\frac12)\right]
\end{align}
$$
Throwing the last expression to WA give us
$$\mathcal{I} \sim -0.18490339160722117817295686175099263891533938048269736635284...$$
consistent with what will get if you ask WA to numerically evaluate the original integral.

**Notes**

$[\color{blue}{1}]$ $(\alpha)_k = \alpha(\alpha+1)\cdots(\alpha+k-1)$ is the rising [Pochhammer symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol).
$[\color{blue}{2}]$ We are using the identity $\frac{(\gamma)_k}{(\gamma+1)_k} = \frac{\gamma}{\gamma+k}$ here.

Comment: What's $\left(-\frac13\right)_k$ mean?

Comment: @dfeuer, $(\alpha)_k = \alpha(\alpha+1)\cdots(\alpha+k-1)$, the rising [Pochhammer symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol)